# How to edit text migrated into Careers2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have migrated my careers account to 2.0 and found a piece of text that I previously have entered but cannot change now.

How do I edit the text below the "name and location" header and above the "Interested in" section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the top "Experience" section?